# Is it possible to replace method of all objects using it as implementation of a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uimenucontroller, swizzling

Is it possible to replace method of all objects using it as implementation of a protocol?

The method is `canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender`:

```
- (BOOL)myCanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
```

The initial problem: can't disable "Cut, Copy, Paste" and "Select, Select All" popup menu on UIWebView. Some strange object generates them on its `canPerformAction` method. And I can't find this object to replace method only on its class.

Very hope to your help. Can't solve this problem for a long time. All other methods to disable selection also disables user input on my page. And I may only replace `canPerformAction` method of correct or all classes to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a category for class NSObject and swizzle its method.

```
@interface NSObject (myCanPerformAction)

- (BOOL)myCanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender;

@end
```